# CSS question: how to add a class to all <a> tags in a list

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am migrating to bootstrap4 from bootstrap 3.
To work well, I must markup the menus with HTML like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="foo">Foo</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="bar">Bar</a></li>
        .
        .
        .
    </ul>
```

where each  element gets the same classes.

This is a part of a jinja2 template in Django.
It seems tedious to "decorate" each  tag with `class="nav-item nav-link"`
I didn't need to do this with the bootstrap3 code (which I inherited and I know little about this)

Is there a different way of doing this?

Comment: use js =>  document.querySelectorAll("a").classList.add("nav-item nav-link");                         
 if specific anchor tags then specify them on selector

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode you can use shortcut `ctrl+alt+DownArrow` to duplicate coursor to bottom lines and edit multiple in the same time.